# How to control URL of anything from Firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am making my college news feed app using `Firebase`, in which there is a list of items having an `image`, title and description. I want that if a user clicks on the list item, it automatically downloads the PDF file related to that news. So in the future, if I want to add some more news, How can I add the `PDF` to that new item? , or if I want to replace the old `PDF` link to new `PDF link` then how I can do that ?. Basically, I want a control on the `firebase database` So that I can change anytime the PDF link in my database.

Main Activity:

```
package com.namy86.dtu_saforum;

import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private RecyclerView mBloglist;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference mReference;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);


        mBloglist=(RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.blog);
        mBloglist.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mBloglist.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mReference=database.getReference();



    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ModelClass,BlogViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter=new
                FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ModelClass,BlogViewHolder>(ModelClass.class,R.layout.design_row,BlogViewHolder.class,mReference){

            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(BlogViewHolder viewHolder, ModelClass model,int position){


                viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
                viewHolder.setDesc(model.getDesc());
                viewHolder.setImage(getApplicationContext(),model.getImage(),model.getFile());
            }

                };
        mBloglist.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);


    }


public class BlogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    View mView;
    Context ctx;
    TextView post,description;
    DownloadManager dm;
    ImageView postImage;
    public BlogViewHolder(View itemView){

        super(itemView);
        mView=itemView;

//        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View view) {
////                Intent browserIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://dtu.ac.in/Web/notice/2017/dec/file1219.pdf"));
////
////                Intent browserChooserIntent=Intent.createChooser(browserIntent,"Choose Browser Of Your Choice");
////                view.getContext().startActivity(browserChooserIntent);
//
////                TextView post2=(TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.titletext);
////                TextView description2=(TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.titletext2);
////                ImageView postImage2=(ImageView)mView.findViewById(R.id.images);
////
////                post2.setText(String.valueOf(post));
////                description2.setText(String.valueOf(description));
////                Picasso.with(ctx).load(String.valueOf(postImage)).into(postImage2);
//
//                dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
//                Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fir-dtu.appspot.com/o/Kaushik%20and%20Kaushik.pdf?alt=media&token=45d80725-dd37-4825-8c7d-23b0dbd50d17");
//                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
//                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
//
//                Long reference = dm.enqueue(request);
//
//
//
//
//
//
//
//
//            }
//        });
    }

    public void setTitle(String title){

        TextView post=(TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.titletext);
        post.setText(title);


    }
    public void setDesc(String desc){

        TextView description=(TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.titletext2);
        description.setText(desc);


    }

    public void setImage(Context ctx, String image, final String file){

        ImageView postImage=(ImageView)mView.findViewById(R.id.images);
        Picasso.with(ctx).load(image).into(postImage);


        postImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(file);
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

                Long reference = dm.enqueue(request);
            }
        });
    }


}
}
```

Comment: @AlexMamo Please See My Code and tell me my mistakes

Comment: You can easily manage your database from the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com) and change the url anytime. I don't understand what problem you're facing.

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes Ya I know but the problem is that  My app is crashing , idk what the errors are.

Comment: When the app crashes, there's an Exception shown on the logcat. Please edit your question and paste the logcat so we can help you